# Gift After Jason?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Max's Dad Kevin loves puzzles. He has a gift for his son but wants him to guess when he will give him the gift.

Kevin leaves some messages. Could you help Max in finding when he would receive his gift?

Message 1

[image]

Message 2

[image]

Message 3

[image]

Comment: "After Jason" made me think of Jason Voorhees. A Friday 13th in 2020 was in March and November, so "after" would mean Saturday 14th in March or November (technically, could be any later day). Well, November 14th won't work very well with a puzzle posted on December 8th...

One possible issue, apart from me barking up the wrong tree: anything given as a present in December 2020 would be either for Christmas or a birthday. If there one single present, it's probably Christmas. So if Max learns from his dad that he'll receive a present in December, no big guesses there.

Nice riddle, though!

Comment: Thanks Klaws! :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let's take these puzzles one at a time...

**Puzzle 1:**

> Here 'seven' is a hint that we should be thinking about numbers depicted **on a seven-segment display** (like a calculator). With that in mind, we then need to take the **inverse** of the segments displayed to the left, i.e. what number can you form with just those segments that are *not* shown here. The answer is: **2020**. This gives us a year...
>
>  [image]

**Puzzle 2:**

> This puzzle gives us the month, since the letters of 'Jason' are the initial letters of **July, August, September, October and November**. What comes after these in the sequence? **December**, of course!

**Puzzle 3:**

> To interpret this puzzle, note that the '*light in night*' must be the **moon** and the '*light in day*' the **sun**. Moreover, these are giving us clues to days of the week, since etymologically speaking Monday is named after the moon and Sunday after the sun.
>
>  So if we count on '*four more*' from Monday or '*five more*' from Sunday, we reach the same day of the week: **Friday**.
>
>  Moreover, we are told to do this '*four times*' - in other words, we want the **fourth Friday of the month**.

**The answer then...**

> ...is the *fourth Friday of December 2020*, and - well, would you look at that - it just happens to be **Christmas Day**! Keep counting those Advent calendar doors, Max - you don't have long to wait now!

Comment: Well done, I couldn't quite get my finger on puzzle 3.

Comment: @hexomino Thanks - yes, that part took me the longest to decipher, and I got stuck on the significance of the 'four times' part for a while. I had a hunch as to what the answer *should* be, and it took a little thought to work backwards from there!

Comment: Excellent Stiv!